# Custom event in backbone.js without bind

Tags: backbone.js

I am looking for a better way to implement a PubSub type functionality with Backbone. I currently am achieving it this, but am looking for a better way to go about it.

Sample Routing Code

```
var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
   customEvents: _.extend({}, Backbone.Events),

   routes: {
     "login": "login"
   },

   //Injecting custom event
   login: function(){
       this.before(function () {
           app.showView('#Content', new LoginView({customEvents:this.customEvents}), "login", true);

     }); 
   },

    //Injecting custom event
   otherView: function(){
       this.before(function () {
           app.showView('#Header', new OtherView({customEvents:this.customEvents}), "login", true);

     }); 
   },

    ..... more code

});
```

Sample View code. Notice that I am using bind to listen for customEvent. This works fine, but looking for alternative method

```
LoginView = Backbone.View.extend({
   initialize: function(options){
      this.customEvents = options.customEvents;
      this.customEvents.bind('app:loggedin', this.loggedIn);

   },

   loggedIn: function(){
       console.log("LOG CHANGED");
   },

 ...more code
```

I'd much rather keep my events with the rest of the events that I am using in my View.  Not sure how to achieve this. Should I be extending the View class?

What I'd like to do on my Views

```
  LoginView = Backbone.View.extend({
    events: {
         "app:loggin" : "loggedIn"
     },

     loggedIn: function(){
       console.log("LOG CHANGED");
    },

 ...more code
```

Comment: `events` is already reserved for the UI events. I would suggest to extend `Backbone.View` and implement this functionality there. I will write this method as soon as I got some free time, this will be very useful not only for you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gist : https://gist.github.com/vermilion1/5600032

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/vpetrychuk/3NVG9/1

Code preview :

```
// -- BASE VIEW ------------------

var BaseView = Backbone.View.extend({
    constructor : function (options) {
        Backbone.View.prototype.constructor.apply(this, arguments);
        this._eventAggregator = options && options.eventAggregator || this;
        this._parseTriggers();
    },
    _parseTriggers :  function () {
        _.each(this.triggers || {}, function (fn, event) {
            var handler = this[fn];
            if (_.isFunction(handler)) {
                this.listenTo(this._eventAggregator, event, handler);
            }
        },
        this);
    }
});

// -- TEST ------------------

var View = BaseView.extend({
    triggers : {
        'hello' : 'helloHandler',
        'bye' : 'byeHandler'
    },
    helloHandler :  function (name) {
        console.log('hello, ' + name);
    },
    byeHandler :  function (name) {
        console.log('bye, ' + name);
    }
});

var view1 = new View();
view1.trigger('hello', 'dude 1'); // -> hello, dude 1
view1.trigger('bye', 'dude 1'); // -> bye, dude 1 

var vent = _.extend({}, Backbone.Events);
var view2 = new View({eventAggregator:vent});
vent.trigger('hello', 'dude 2'); // -> hello, dude 2
vent.trigger('bye', 'dude 2'); // -> bye, dude 2
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks like exactly what I am looking for, gonna give it a shot this weekend. Should there be a similar function that unbinds the events on a close method for example?  Thinking something like 
Backbone.View.prototype.close = function () {
    this.remove();
    this.unbind();
};

Comment: I have updated the example by using `listenTo` method. In this case there is no need to unbind this triggers, bindings will "die" with the view.

Comment: Just to be clear, when you write 

var vent = _.extend({}, Backbone.Events);
var view2 = new View({eventAggregator:vent});

You are doing the same thing I was doing, injecting a global event "vent" that gets shared across views.  This way I could both broadcast across various View at the same time, and also keep the View itself cleaner by using triggers object.